# How to get deviceName value from Multicapabilities definition in protractor config

Tags: jasmine, protractor

This might be repeated question for you guys but really I didn't get answer yet.
Here is my multi-capabilities definition in protractor config file.
I want to access the deviceName parameter value. How can I do it?

```
exports.config = {
directConnect:true,
multiCapabilities: [
{
browserName: 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'mobileEmulation': {
                'deviceName': 'iPad'
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Tried under onPrepare but not giving multi-capabilities values

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function(c) {
        console.log(c.get('deviceName'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about solving with `getCapabilities()`, but you should be able to solve this with [getProcessedConfig()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig).

`getProcessedConfig` will return a promise of your entire configuration settings (and a few protractor defaults).  So taking your example:

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then((c) => {
    console.log(c.capabilities.chromeOptions.mobileEmulation.deviceName);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make `console.log(process.env)` in the `onPrepare` block and find what you want.

Comment: He will find `deviceName` in environment variables

Comment: Looks to me like's he's emulating a different device than what he's running on

Comment: I am emulating the screen as iPhone 7 on Chrome browser that why I need multiple device configurations like Galaxy S5, iPad etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try `getProcessedConfig()`
http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.getProcessedConfig

Or just plain old stupid:

```
let device_name = 'iPad' 
exports.config = {
   directConnect: true,
   multiCapabilities: [{
   browserName: 'chrome',
   chromeOptions: {
      mobileEmulation: {
           deviceName: device_name
        }
      }
   }],
   onPrepare: function () {
       console.log('Device name will be', device_name);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetching device name worked as advised by Gunderson but now I am running into different issue I am unable to access the variable value outside the code block while in onPrepare.

```
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (c) {
        return global.deviceName 
c.capabilities.chromeOptions.mobileEmulation.deviceName;
    }).then(function () {
            console.log("Device Name is:" + global.deviceName);
            customDevice = global.deviceName;
        }
    );
};
```

customDevice not printing any value.....which is define as global variable on top of the configuration file.

I know might be doing silly mistake in accessing it...:)